# How to create two square sine waves with exact same function but differing x-values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to construct two square sine waves that describe the SAME function, BUT, they should have differing starting points on the x axis. One should start at 0 and go to 2pi, and the other from 0.05 and go to 2pi+0.05. They should both have a step size of 1. For a normal sine wave, this is easy:

```
n = int(2*numpy.pi//0.1)

x_train = numpy.linspace(0, 2*numpy.pi, n)
x_test = numpy.linspace(0.05, 2*numpy.pi+0.05, n)

ysin_train = numpy.sin(2*x_train)
ysin_test = numpy.sin(2*x_test)

plt.plot(x_train, ysin_train)
plt.plot(x_test, ysin_test)
plt.show()
```

The plot will show you that the two curves are exactly the same, except for their starting points. For the square wave, it's not as obvious what to do. I've tried this:

```
from scipy import signal

ysquare_train = signal.square(2*x_train)
ysquare_test = signal.square(2*x_test)

plt.plot(x_train, ysquare_train)
plt.plot(x_test, ysquare_test)
```

But the two curves clearly do not describe the same function, `ysquare_test` is 0.05 units ahead of `ysquare_train`. How can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You suffer from discrete spacing issues. Try increasing the number of points:

```
n = int(2*numpy.pi//0.01)
```

(BTW: the int is redundant here since you using the // operator)

Comment: So you're saying the square sine wave starts att 0 no matter what x-vector I feed to `signal.square`?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Your code with larger `n` will show indeed two overlapping functions, with one starting from 0 and one starting from 0.05.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So is this an issue with matplotlibs plotting or scipy's `signal` function?

Comment: Not really. It just the way you sampled your function which was not dense enough. To understand try plotting with points marker '.'.